# Socket.io create one object every 2 connections

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, socket.io

I am trying to make a game where every 2 socket.io connections are put together into  into one "game"/ room . I have managed to put the two connections into one room but i also want to have one game object for these two connection. But my code creates two one for every connection basically.

```
//My Class     
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.players = [];
    this.nextPlayer = [];

  }
  //...My Methods go here 
}
```

This is the part that gave me issues.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  //Puts every 2 connections into 1 room together
  if (io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room-" + roomno] && io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room-" + roomno].length > 1) roomno++;
  socket.join("room-" + roomno);
  io.sockets.in("room-"+roomno).emit('connectedToRoom', "You are in room no. "+roomno);

  if (io.nsps["/"].adapter.rooms["room-1"].length === 2) {
    //I think the problem is here it creates a new Game() for every connection
    //I would like to have only one game object for every 2 connections
    let game = new Game();
    game.players = Object.keys(io.nsps["/"].adapter.rooms["room-1"].sockets);
    game.nextPlayer = Object.keys(io.nsps["/"].adapter.rooms["room-1"].sockets)[0];

    socket.on("fieldMarked", (data) => {
      //This is different based on which client sent the "fieldMarked"
      console.log(game.nextPlayer);
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Is the 2nd if statement checking for rooms["room-1"] instead of rooms["room-" + roomno] a typo when copying this code over to stackoverflow? Otherwise if there are 2 clients in room-1 it will create a new game object for every new connection.

Comment: Yes the "room-1" i put in for testing i think, I got my problem solved by creating a global array to store all the "game" objects.